# Managing links and directories

Tags: php

I have recently started a larger project than I'm used to, and I'm finding it hard to manage links (such as including files) with all the directories.

Is there a way I can define a basepath and then go from there.

So something like this:

```
require(BASEPATH.'/folder/file.php');
```

instead of:

```
require('../../folder/file.php');
```

So basically a way so that the links won't break if files are moved.

Comment: Are you looking for [`define`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)?

Answer (score 1):

You can always store or define a variable based on the value of [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) in your index file/front controller:

```
// in index.php
define('BASE_DIR', __DIR__);
```

In other files, you will now be able to reference the base directory like so:

```
// in some_other.php
require(BASE_DIR . '/folder/file.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

So you're saying you've started a large project - then you DO IT right from very beginning i.e from the current point.

I'd suggest you to create `const.php` contained this:

```
<?php

$constants = array(

   'DS' => DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, //shorthand
   'ROOT' => __DIR__,
   'LIBS' => ROOT . '/libs'
);

//and so on - add more


//Define each one now:
foreach ($constants as $const => $val ){
  define($const, $val);
}
```

Any file of your project:

```
<?php


require ('../const.php');


//now constants are available and you can access them:
require ROOT . 'some.php'; //etc etc
require ROOT . 'another.php';
```

Comment: Defining your constants early is the best way to go.

Comment: In my example - this is very beginning - as I said - include them in any file of the project

Comment: You can't automatically include variables (or a file) in all files without doing something like extending a class or something.

Comment: You're talking about the scopes. But constants are different - you'd only define them and can access them from any class or function. Also it's still possible to use spl_auto_load_register($custom_auto_load_function) to implement own function / var / class loader